# When to use Singleton Pattern in ASP.Net in place of using Application State

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, singleton

Can someone please provide scenarios where Singleton Pattern can be used to store commonly used data in Asp.net application, which is expensive to retrieve on each request ? Also, is it better to use Application State for the same?
Also, can Singleton Pattern be used to store Web.Config settings when the application is started ?

Comment: This fascination with patterns... anyway, [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used) might help you. As for one of the details of your question - web.config values are already cached, you don't need any extraneous extra technology around it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303725/asp-net-application-state-vs-a-static-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no simple way of using Singleton pattern in ASP.Net ,I would prefer wrapping session state object in a static class,since a session is one for the entire application (but different for every user).

Application state is already kind of Singleton in the sense it's one for every use and entire application.

I would not prefer to store Web.Config anywhere else you can make a wrapper class for it if you like.

**Some Related Post:**

[Asp.net cache singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502584/asp-net-cache-singleton-pattern)
[Asp.net singleton pattern scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934606/asp-net-singleton-pattern-scenario)
[Singleton pattern Asp.net csharp for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728678/singleton-pattern-asp-net-c-sharp-for-each-user)

Comment: @J.Steen You are right that's what I intended to mean by different browser ,let me clarify my post